# How to add a SQL Azure database and Service Bus to a Virtual Network?

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking, azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm having trouble with Virtual Networks on Azure and I'm very new to all this, so apologies in advance if my question is rather naive.

**Problem:**
I have a "azure cloud service" (a web application) that has now been added to a azure virtual network. But now it is not able to connect to the SQL Azure database with the following error message:

`SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)]`

A Virtual network has been created via the Azure portal following these steps:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/create-a-virtual-network/

Then I added the following config to ServiceConfiguration.cscf

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
  <VirtualNetworkSite name="SomeNetwork" />
   <AddressAssignments>
     <InstanceAddress roleName="Some.Web.App">
      <Subnets>
    <Subnet name="AName" />
   </Subnets>
 </InstanceAddress>
</AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

**Question**
How do I add SQL server to the Virtual network somehow? I have read a few articles and all are directing towards creating a VM in azure and then adding the VM to the virtual network? Is this the only way?
The web application also uses Azure Service Bus and it too now has connectivity issues due to the virtual network. I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid manual whitelisting of IP addresses on database level by simply making your Azure SQL database a 'linked resource' in your Cloud settings (Cloud -> pick yours -> "Linked Resources").

That way you can connect to Azure SQL Database from cloud app with no extra configuration, except using existing database connection params.

Comment: Where can I find this menu?